# Can't get ARA to work on non-default directory

Tags: python, ansible

I'm not installing ARA in the default location, nor do I have "root" on this server. So I'm doing the installation with a "service account" called service_acct. 
This had lead me to having to do some tricks to get me this far, where I had to set the PYTHONUSERBASE to a directory (ARA is the only thing using Python on this server, so it should be fine).

```
export PYTHONUSERBASE=/dsk01/software/ara
```

I installed these prerequisite:

```
gcc python-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel redhat-rpm-config


python get-pip.py --user
pip install --user ara
```

I've added the below Environment Variables to the system account that runs ARA, and the user account that will run the Ansible plays. I can see these values when I grep "printenv".

```
ARA_DATABASE=sqlite:////dsk01/software/ara/.ara/ansible.sqlite
ARA_DIR=/dsk01/software/ara/.ara
ARA_LOG_FILE=/dsk01/software/ara/.ara/ara.log
ARA_HOST=42.34.25.77
ARA_PORT=9191
PYTHONUSERBASE=/dsk01/software/ara
```

Here is the ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
callback_plugins=/dsk01/software/ara/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ara/plugins/callbacks
action_plugins=/dsk01/software/ara/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ara/plugins/actions


[ara]
dir = /dsk01/software/ara/.ara
host = 42.34.25.77
port = 9191
logfile = /dsk01/software/ara/.ara/ara.log
database = sqlite:////dsk01/software/ara/.ara/ansible.sqlite
local_tmp = /dsk01/software/ara/.ansible/tmp
```

When I access the ARA web interface, but it's saying:

**The ARA database is empty or the web application is not configured properly to find your playbook data.**

I'm just relying on the default webserver and database. So I haven't configured the webserver settings or anything on the sqlite DB.

when I run an Ansible-playbook, it's giving me the error message:

**[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/dsk01/software/ara/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ara/plugins/callbacks/log_ara.py) as it seems to
be invalid: Unable to configure handler 'ara_file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/service_acct/.ara/ara.log'**

ARA keeps on writing it's log files to /home/service_acct/.ara/ara.log. I can see the writes when I start the webserver with: ara-manage runserver. It never writes anything to /dsk01/software/ara/.ara/ara.log.

It's odd, since ARA is using the custom settings (for example the IP) that I've set as far as the IP of the server and port.
start So it keeps on trying to write log files to the Service Account (service_acct), instead of the location where I've setup ARA.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue.

There is a discrepancy between the documentation and what the code actually does. So it looks like "ARA_LOG_FILE" is used to name the log file, not state the path to the log file.

https://github.com/openstack/ara/blob/ce18a5543bf0550be8e727dc18a6453b9c2d111a/ara/config/logger.py#L82-L84